# Netbeans 7.4 CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, netbeans-7

I have two installations of NetBeans on a Windows machine..both running 7.4 but that might not be the case in all cases.

The one install is on a USB so it comes and goes but changes I make to it's configurations should not be reflected in the local copy I have initially installed.

How (or is there even a way?) to invoke netbeans.exe with a command line switch to tell it which directory to load it's properties?

It seems as though the USB netbeans inherited all the projects, settings of the default installed version of NB.

Any ideas or suggestions???

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the userdir?

See http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir